# How to reduce time taken For loop in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, numpy, append

I have following python code:

```
H1 = [[0.04,0.03,0.01,0.002],[0.02,0.04,0.001,0.5]]
H2 = [[0.06,0.02,0.02,0.004],[0.8,0.09,0.6,0.1]]    

D1 = [0.01,0.02,0.1,0.01]    
D2 = [0.1,0.3,0.01,0.4] 

Tp = np.sum(D1)    
Tn = np.sum(D2) 

T = []    
append2 = T.append   
E = []    
append3 = E.append   

for h1,h2 in itertools.izip(H1,H2) 
    Err = []    
    append1 = Err.append
    for v in h1:    

        L1 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h1]    
        L2 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h2]    

        Sp = np.dot(D1,L1)     
        Sn = np.dot(D2,L2)    

        err = min(Sp+Tn-Sn, Sn+Tp-Sp)    
        append1(err)  

    b = np.argmin(Err)    
    append2(h1[b])    
    append3(Err[b])
```

This is just an example code. I need to run the inner for loop near about 20,000 times (here it runs just twice). But the inner for loop takes much time making it inpractical to use. 
In line profiler, it shows that line `Sp = np.dot(D1,L1)` , `Sn = np.dot(D2,L2)` and  `b = np.argmin(Err)`  are the most time consuming.
How can I reduce the time taken by above code.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: what's your hardware ? Depending on the computer, you can use multiprocessing (since the code is parallelizable) or even CUDA for GPU computation.

Comment: @georgesl: Hi, I am already using multiprocessing. I need to run above code for 5 different H1 and H2. Again my H1 contain near about 20,000 list i.e the outer for loop runs for 20,000 times.

Comment: Use CUDA, it's dead fast *I reckon it had those python bindings*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the data in ndarray types.  When you do a numpy operation on a list, it has to construct a new array each time.  I modified your code to run a variable number of times and found it too ~1s for 10000 iterations.  Changing the datatypes to ndarrays reduced that by about a factor of two, and I think there is still some improvement to make (the first version of this had a bug that made it execute too fast)

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
N = 10000
H1 = [np.array([0.04,0.03,0.01,0.002])] * N
H2 = [np.array([0.06,0.02,0.02,0.004])] * N

D1 = np.array([0.01,0.02,0.1,0.01]    )
D2 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.01,0.4] )

Tp = np.sum(D1)    
Tn = np.sum(D2) 

T = []    
append2 = T.append   
E = []    
append3 = E.append   

for h1,h2 in itertools.izip(H1,H2):
    Err = []    
    append1 = Err.append
    for v in h1:

        #L1 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h1]    
        #L2 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h2]    
        L1 = h1 > v
        L2 = h2 > v
        Sp = np.dot(D1,L1)     
        Sn = np.dot(D2,L2)    

        err = min(Sp+Tn-Sn, Sn+Tp-Sp)    
        append1(err)  

    b = np.argmin(Err)    
    append2(h1[b])    
    append3(Err[b])
```

Comment: Thanks, this work and reduce ample amount of time. You said, that there is still some improvement. What`s that? I still need to reduce timing factor a bit.

Comment: The other way I see to speed this up to to use broadcasting array operations to remove the inner loop.  For instance `h1 > h1.reshape(len(h1,1))` will compute all of the `L1` vectors in parallel (I think).  The dot product and np.min can operate on whichever axes you want.

Comment: Thanks! I am gong to try this one too.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a pretty big speed boost if you use numpy functions with numpy arrays instead of lists. Most numpy functions will convert lists to arrays internally and that adds a lot of overhead to the run time. Here is a simple example:

```
In [16]: a = range(10)

In [17]: b = range(10)

In [18]: aa = np.array(a)

In [19]: bb = np.array(b)

In [20]: %timeit np.dot(a, b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 54 us per loop

In [21]: %timeit np.dot(aa, bb)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.4 us per loop
```

`numpy.dot` run 16x faster when called with arrays in this case. Also when you use numpy arrays you'll be able to simplify some of your code which should also help it run faster. For example if `h1` is an array, `L1 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h1]` can be written as `h1 > v` which returns an array and should also run faster. Bellow I've gone ahead and replaced your lists with arrays so you can see what it would look like.

```
import numpy as np

H1 = np.array([[0.04,0.03,0.01,0.002],[0.02,0.04,0.001,0.5]])
H2 = np.array([[0.06,0.02,0.02,0.004],[0.8,0.09,0.6,0.1]])

D1 = np.array([0.01,0.02,0.1,0.01])
D2 = np.array([0.1,0.3,0.01,0.4])

Tp = np.sum(D1)    
Tn = np.sum(D2) 

T = np.zeros(H1.shape[0])
E = np.zeros(H1.shape[0])

for i in range(len(H1)):
    h1 = H1[i]
    h2 = H2[i]
    Err = np.zeros(len(h1))

    for j in range(len(h1)):    
        v = h1[j]

        L1 = h1 > v
        L2 = h2 > v

        Sp = np.dot(D1, L1)     
        Sn = np.dot(D2, L2)    

        err = min(Sp+Tn-Sn, Sn+Tp-Sp)    
        Err[j] = err

    b = np.argmin(Err)
    T[i] = h1[b]
    E[i] = Err[b]
```

Once you're more comfortable with numpy arrays you might want to look into expressing at least your inner loop using [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). For some applications, using broadcasting can be much more efficient than python loops. Good luck, hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's some low-hanging fruit in your list comprehensions:

```
L1 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h1]
L2 = [1 if i>=v else 0 for i in h2]
```

The above could be written as:

```
L1 = [i>=v for i in h1]
L2 = [i>=v for i in h2]
```

Because Booleans are a subclass of integers, `True` and `False` are already 1 and 0, just wearing fancy clothes.

```
err = min(Sp+Tn-Sn, Sn+Tp-Sp)    
append1(err)
```

You could combine the above two lines to avoid the variable assignment and access.

If you put the code in a function, all local variable usage will be slightly faster. Also, any global functions or methods you use (e.g. `min`, `np.dot`) can be converted to locals in the function signature using default arguments. `np.dot` is an especially slow call to make (outside of how long the operation itself takes) because it involves an attribute lookup. This would be similar to the optimization you already make with the list `append` methods.

Now I imagine none of this will really affect performance much, since your question really seems to be "how can I make NumPy faster?" (which others are on top of for you) but they might have some impact and be worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood what does the instruction `np.dot()` on two lists of dimensions 1, it seems to me that the following code should do the same as yours.
Could you test its speed , please ?

Its principle is to play on indices instead of the elements of lists, and to use the peculiarity of a list defined as a default value of a function

```
H1 = [[0.04,0.03,0.01,0.002],[0.02,0.04,0.001,0.5]]
H2 = [[0.06,0.02,0.02,0.004],[0.8,0.09,0.6,0.1]]    

D1 = [0.01,0.02,0.1,0.01]    
D2 = [0.1,0.3,0.01,0.4] 

Tp = np.sum(D1)    
Tn = np.sum(D2) 

T,E = [],[]    
append2 = T.append      
append3 = E.append 

ONE,TWO = [],[]

def zoui(v, ONE=ONE,TWO=TWO,
         D1=D1,D2=D2,Tp=Tp,Tn=Tn,tu0123 = (0,1,2,3)):
    diff =  sum(D1[i] if ONE[i]>=v else 0 for i in tu0123)\
           -sum(D2[i] if TWO[i]>=v else 0 for i in tu0123)
    #or maybe
    #diff =  sum(D1[i] * ONE[i]>=v for i in tu0123)\
    #       -sum(D2[i] * TWO[i]>=v for i in tu0123)

    return min(Tn+diff,Tp-diff)

for n in xrange(len(H1)):
    ONE[:] = H1[n]
    TWO[:] = H2[n]
    Err = map(zoui,ONE)
    b = np.argmin(Err)    
    append2(ONE[b])    
    append3(Err[b])
```